# Collections is private

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I keep getting a "collections is private" error. I wanted to create an `ArrayList`. How do you properly extend the `Collections` class?

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class lists extends Collections {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arraylist <Integer> x = new Arraylist<>();
        int[] y = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i<100-1; i++) {
            y[i] = i;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<100-1; j++) {
            Integer z = new Integer(y[j]);
            x.set( j , z );
            System.out.println(x.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a class, you need to import that class.  Not a different class.

Comment: There's *no reason* for you to use that `extends` keyword anyway. You're not even instantiating an instance of `lists`!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you are only trying to use `ArrayList` then you don't need to extend that.

1. It's `ArrayList` (not `Arraylist`)
2. Use `y.length` on your first loop rather than 100-1.
3. You can just use `x.add()` to add your integer value in without setting index it should be added into since there you are strictly specifying a pattern.

Try this solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] y = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i<y.length; i++){
        y[i] = i;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<100-1; j++){
        x.add(new Integer(y[j]));
        System.out.println(x.get(j));
    }
}
```

But, here is better solution, same achievement with one loop:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j<100-1; j++){
        x.add(new Integer(j));
        System.out.println(x.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the source of `Collections` class. Collections class is non-instantiable since it has a private constructor. If you have a Subclass which calls the Collections class, the subclass will invoke the super class constructor since the super class does not define any other constructor to invoke. You cannot instantiate the Collections super class and its sub-classes.

```
// Suppresses default constructor, ensuring non-instantiability.
    private Collections() {
    }
```

From your question, if you want to just instantiate an `ArrayList` class. The line `ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();` will suffice with an import of `java.util.ArrayList`.

Check your code and add variables where needed and you can improve further on the logic.

```
    final int RANGEVAL = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < RANGEVAL -1 ; i++) {  
        x.set( i , i ); //You can also use x.add(i);
        System.out.println(x.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, if all you want to do is create an **instance** of `ArrayList`, there's no reason to extend anything. In your example code there's no need for it.

If you really do want your own collection **class**, then `Collections` is the wrong class. You need to implement [`Collection<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), singular, or [`List<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Implementing those interfaces is a lot of work. You can save a lot of time by sub-classing [`AbstractList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html). When you do that you only have to implement `get(int)` and `size()`; the rest is done for you. If the list is modifiable then you'll also want to override `set(int, E)`, `add(int, E)`, and `remove(int)`.